# LANG environment variable in zsh

Tags: unix, environment-variables, locale, zsh, zshrc

I recently installed sublime text on a new ubuntu machine.
During start up I get the following error message :

> Your system's locale is set to a value that can not handle non-ASCII
>   characters. Package Control can not properly work unless this is
>   fixed.
>
> On Linux, please reference your distribution's docs for information on
>   properly setting the LANG environmental variable. As a temporary
>   work-around, you can launch Sublime Text from the terminal with:
>
> ```
>    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sublime_text
> ```

I checked for the following in the terminal (zsh shell) `echo $LANG` but this does not return anything i added the following two lines to the `~/.profile` and restarted the terminal, but this did not help as `echo $LANG` did not return anything ?

How can I set my `LANG` env variable in zsh shell ?

Answer (score 15):

### User

you can declare and export the `LANG` environment variable in your `~/.zshrc`

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Logout and log-in again to activate.

### System-wide

For a system wide configuration edit `/etc/default/locale` as follow:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
```

### Check

You can get [information about your locale](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#List_current_settings) with:

```
locale
```

Answer (score 2):

first:

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install locales
```

and the famous:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This rids the system of locales, then re-installs locales and downgrades libc6 from 2.19 to 2.13 which is the issue. Then configures locales again.